# prev() method is not applying to the previous element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The `prev().remove()` is not removing the previous sibling of the element.

There is a div with class `crossSign` after every `li` element, which is inside an a element. When the `li` is clicked, I want to remove its previous element and itself.

It's not happening. Can someone tell me another what is wrong or any other technique to do this.

```js
$newform.on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $newform.find('input:text').val();
  var url = document.getElementById('addurl').value;
  $list.append('<a href="' + url + '"><li class="links"><span>' + text + '</span></li></a><div class="crossSign"><div class="line1"></div><div class="line2"></div></div>');
  //$list.append('<div class="crossSign"><div class="line1"></div><div class="line2"></div></div>');
  //$('a').attr('href', url);
  $newform.find('input:text').val('');
  $addurl.val('');
});

$('#close-form').on('click', function() {
  $newform.hide();
  $newlinks.show();
});

$('.crossSign').on('click', function() {
  $(this).prev().remove();
  $(this).remove();
});

$('.crossSign').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).show();
});

$('.crossSign').on('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});

$('a').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).next().show();
});

$('a').on('mouseout', function() {
  $(this).next().hide();
});
});
```

```html
<div id="list-div">
  <a href="https://www.example.com">
    <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
  </a>
  <div class="crossSign">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="https://www.example.com">
    <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
  </a>
  <div class="crossSign">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="https://www.example.com">
    <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
  </a>
  <div class="crossSign">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="https://www.example.com">
    <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
  </a>
  <div class="crossSign">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="https://www.example.com">
    <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
  </a>
  <div class="crossSign">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
  </div>
  <a href="https://www.example.com">
    <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
  </a>
  <div class="crossSign">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"There is a div of class crossSign after every li element "_ ... which is invalid HTML to begin with. Either write a _proper_ list, or stop using `li` elements in such a place - they can't stand "naked" on their own, they must be children of a list element.

Comment: Despite the above (which is a valid point), [that seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/qs513uwt/) at least on Chrome, if I comment out the `$newform` part (since I don't know what element that is) and the errant `});` at the bottom.

Comment: I don't know what damn problem is but, it is only applying to the first element and not the same with other elements. I've checked everything (classes, id, elements), but don't know what the heck is wrong. If i click the crossSign div its only removes the first element in the list, if i click the other crossSign it does not work. I've also changed the li to p.

Answer (score -1):

To improve the solution just add an extra parent "div" and use $(this).parent().remove() to remove the entire parent like this:

```
$('.crossSign').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

and create the parent on each group:

```
<div id="list-div">
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
    </a>
    <div class="crossSign">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
    </a>
    <div class="crossSign">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
    </a>
    <div class="crossSign">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
    </a>
    <div class="crossSign">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
    </a>
    <div class="crossSign">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.example.com">
      <li class="links"><span>example</span></li>
    </a>
    <div class="crossSign">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```